# I want To append Some data in the File at specific location With the java Code

Tags: java, file-io, append, read-write

I want to append some data in a file the java code.

My file contains the following data:

```
#JSGF V1.0;

/**
 * JSGF Grammar for Hello World example
 */

grammar hello;

public <greet> = (ANKIT)|(BHAVIK)|(MONIL)|(JAY)|(HIREN)|(KRUTIKA)|(RIKIN)|(YAGNESH)|(KRISHNA);
```

and I want that whenever I append file that data come before the `;` charachter

So if I add JAYA then it appends like following :

```
public <greet> = (ANKIT)|(BHAVIK)|(MONIL)|(JAY)|(HIREN)|(KRUTIKA)|(RIKIN)|(YAGNESH)|(KRISHNA)|(JAYA);
```

Please give me some proper suggession or sample code for this.

i had Done like this to achive this kind of stuff as follows..

try {
                        File f = new File("E:\NEw_Workspace\Voice_recognition_modify\src\edu\cmu\sphinx\demo\helloworld\hello.gram");
                        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw");

```
                    // Read a character
                   // char ch = raf.readChar();

                    // Seek to end of file
                    raf.seek((f.length())-1);

                    // Append to the end
                    raf.writeChars("|(ASHISH);");
                    raf.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
```

but i am getting an the out put in file like follows:
"A "then some square box image" then s "then some square box image" and so on

Comment: It appears you want to *replace* the line which occurs *after* the second `;` with the text you want. Or you want to append `|(word)` before the last `;`. Can you clarify?

Comment: This is not a clear question. please describe more before removing it by stackoverflow guys! ;)

Comment: i want to append |(word) after second ; and evry time it should be appended before the 2nd ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had Done that With the Following Code ..Got success.

```
               File f = new File("E:\\NEw_Workspace\\Voice_recognition_modify\\src\\edu\\cmu\\sphinx\\demo\\helloworld\\hello.gram");
                    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw");

                    // Read a character
                   // char ch = raf.readChar();

                    // Seek to end of file
                    raf.seek((f.length())-1);

                    // Append to the end
                    raf.write(("|(KARAN);").getBytes());

                    raf.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a FileReader/FileWriter combination.

Read each line and then check if the last character is ;. If it is then insert your input before this ; I think the apache libraries have a method to insert strings inside another string. Or you could write a method yourself

Or you could use RandomAccessFile and open the file is rw mode. Then you could amend the existing file. You could use the same process of calling readLine() and checking for ;
An example of using RandomAccessFile is [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/UseRandomAccessFile.html)

One question though - is there only ever one line ending in ;

In rough untested code

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/fileIn"));
String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/tmp/fileOut"));
    if (str.endsWith(";") { 
        //insert the variable before the ; here
    }
    out.write(str);
    out.close();
}
in.close();
```

My memory is not too good on RandmonAccessFile but the above should roughly work although RandomAccessFile would be cleaner if the ; is always the last character

Comment: yes..there should be owlays one line ending in ;...cant u provide me some sample code...?

Comment: See update to answer. It's untested but should get you closer

Comment: I dont want to remove anythng ..its jus removing ma data and i have to append string before the 2nd time ";" not before first occurence of ";"

Comment: So is there one or two ; Your two comments say different things